# How to call view block on click?

Tags: views, nodes, ajax, javascript

I have a page/node that contains 15 view blocks, each view block has many fields and all of this causes the page to load really slow.

How do I load the view block only when I need it? for example I would click a button/div (venue) then the view block venue will load instead of invoking all of the view blocks on the template and letting it load all at once.

UPDATE:
I tried using ajax but it's not working even though I turned the ajax on the view block.

This the code I used:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#getvenue").click(function(){
    $.ajax(
    Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
    {

    view_name: 'custom_package_form',view_display_id: 'block_56'
    },

    function(response)
    {
        if (response[1] !== undefined) 
        {
            var viewHtml = response[1].data;
            $("#output-venue").html(viewHtml);

            Drupal.attachBehaviors();
        }
        else {
            $("#output-venue").html("NONE");
        }


    });
    });
 });
```

Node Venue TPL:

```
<button id="getvenue"> GET VENUE </button>
<div id="output-venue"></div>
```

Nothing happens, I tried alerting the var viewHtml to see if it has something, the alert only shows null.

What's wrong with the JS? Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$.ajax({
    url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'view_name=custom_package_form&view_display_id=block_56',
    success: function(response) {
      var output = response[1].data;
      $("#output-venue").html(output);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('An error occured!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I tried this code, it's giving a null on the #output-venue div. It only appeared when I put "$("#output-venue").text(output);" to the js instead of html. I was wondering if the url is correct? I only based the coding to this link: http://blog.astaz3l.com/2013/06/24/drupal-views-ajax/

Comment: The response from the server is important. use `alert(output)` to make sure it is correct. Then you can display it in any way you want. What `url` you are talking about?

Comment: The alert shows "null" also. As for the url, I was referring this part: `url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax', ` I'm not sure if that is default? sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I used this code in a few websites and it works. Yes it is default

Comment: In View settings did you set  the `Use Ajax : Yes`?

Comment: Yes, I did set it. I will try to create a new view block, because the one I'm using is on modal.

Comment: It's working, if the block doesn't have contextual filter. it shows null if I use contextual filter. Thank you again

Comment: @Danz you welcome

Comment: Hi @Danz , how did you get this done? I'm trying to so the exact same thing... where did you put the code? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Drii7, you can put the ajax code on your js file. In my case the ajax code is under click function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this module [ajaxblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks), I have used it with ubercart for building e-commerce site.

> Permits to load some blocks by additional AJAX request after loading the whole cached page when the page is viewed by anonymous user. It is suitable for sites which are mostly static, and the page caching for anonymous users is a great benefit, but there are some pieces of information that have to be dynamic.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying out the module you recommended. I saw this: "Time in milliseconds to wait before block loading" on the settings of the blocks. I don't like the blocks to be loaded by some given time, I would like the blocks to be loaded individually when triggering an OnClick of a button. Is that possible? Because I would like the page to be as light as it can be, the 15 blocks should not be invoked/loaded on the page/tpl as long as the button that will call the block is not clicked. thanks again